# gulp browserify bundle time takes too long

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify

I've ran into a strange issue and need your help to figure what's going on.

I've configured gulp to build my a test up written in **React.js** in ES6. I've used `browserify` to setup the CommonJS env and `babelify` for bigger ES6 support. And everything works, it just takes too long (in my opinion) to build if **React** is required as CommonJS module. Meaning this

```
import React from 'react';
```

line will raise the bundle/compile time from `1.2secs` to around `4secs` on the initial build, then when any changes are detected it takes around `2.5secs` to rebuild the js files. And this time rapidly goes up when more modules are included. My work around was to configure `bower` to expose any external libraries as globals in the browser, don't like this solution as much.

Here is my main `browserify` setup:

```
function buildApp () {
  return browserify({
    entries: config.paths.jsx,
    extensions: ['.jsx'],
    debug: true
  })
  .bundle()
  .on('error', onError)
  .pipe(source('app.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dest));
}
```

and the transform is added via `packages.json`

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "babelify"
  ]
}
```

I did try the `ignore` option in my *buildApp* `function` as follows:

```
transform(babelify.configure({
  ignore: /node_modules/
})
```

but that did not help.

I'm using the latest packages, as far as I know, meaning:

```
"babelify": "^6.3.0",
"browserify": "^11.2.0",
"react": "^0.14.0"
```

on Node v4.1.0. Anyone has any ideas? By all means, please share.

P.S.
[Here](https://github.com/radical-edo/react-todos) is the link to the repo if someone has the time and wants to take a closer look. Or, maybe, test the build time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because React goes and requires a couple of things which means your browserify has to traverse through more nodes.

One way you might be able to improve this is to prebundle React. However, this would only improve the React library, add another library and it will slow down again.

One thing you can use to improve **rebundling** is by adding watchify to your browserify bundle process.

Give this a try

```
var watchify = require('watchify');
var babelify = require('babelify');

var bundler;

function buildApp () {
  bundler = bundler || watchify(browserify({
    entries: config.paths.jsx,
    extensions: ['.jsx'],
    debug: true,
    transform: [babelify], //This will allow you to use babel for jsx/es6
    cache: {}, // required for watchify
    packageCache: {}, // required for watchify
    fullPaths: true //You can change this false in production
  }))

  return bundler
  .bundle()
  .on('error', onError)
  .pipe(source('app.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dest));
}
```

Essentially what you need to do is wrap your browserify in a watchify and add some extra properties (cache, packageCache, fullPaths)

Watchify will speed up your rebundling process by caching the bundled files.

**!Important Note**

Remember to remove watchify in production, unless you're build process will hang since it's watching your files.

Comment: I've added the `watchify` with the needed options, didn't work, rebundling process stays the same.

Comment: Did you add the cache, packageCache and fullPaths?

Comment: Indeed I have, passed to `browserify`'s options object.

Comment: Opps, changed it abit, try this

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped immensely!

Comment: Nice, 7s down to 500ms!

Comment: Do I need to pass so params to (cache, packageCache)? Because I wrapped my browserify into watchify and compilation time was riched from 1.7s to 1.9s.

Comment: @Nazariy This isn't about first compilation btw, it's about subsequent compilations, i.e when you change a file and it recompiles for you. Hence having the cache/packageCache variables allows you to cache your bundled code so we can recompile the changes faster. There is no way we can escape the long time taken for the first compilation afaik.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look on my repo https://github.com/skrobek/react-gulp-browserify. I'm using exactly the same tech stack: gulp, browserify, react.

Comment: I've took a look at your config, as far as i could see the difference was that you hooked up on the `update` event, tried that, but it didn't help me much