# Babel taking 30+ seconds to start & end with Gulp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, babeljs

So we're using `Gulp` & have tasks inside that transform `React/ES6 (Babel)` code to javascript.

I've noticed that it always takes 30+ seconds to transform even if only a small change was made. E.g If I were to add a space and save it would still take `30+secs` for babel to start & finish.

Does anyone know why this may be happening? Below is part of my `gulp.js` file.

```
gulp.task('babel', function () {
  return browserify({
    entries: 'app/index.js',
    extensions: ['.js'],
    presets: ["es2015", "react"],
    debug: true,
    paths: ['app', 'app/layouts','app/components', 'node_modules']
  })
    .transform(babelify)
    .on('error', log_error)
    .bundle()
    .on('error', log_error)
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.app.dist));
});
gulp.task('watch', ['build'],  function() {
  gulp.watch(path.assets.src+'icons/*', ['icons', 'sass']);
  gulp.watch(path.styles.all, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(path.styles.all, ['sass:styleguide']);
  gulp.watch(path.scripts.all, ['babel']);
  gulp.watch(path.templates.all, ['copy:html']);
});
```

I've tried adding a `watchify` around the `browseryify` ( In reference to this post [gulp browserify bundle time takes too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073704/gulp-browserify-bundle-time-takes-too-long) ) But this made no improvement. All I did in reference to that post was wrap a `watchify( browserify({....}))` around the browserify &  add the required cache fields.

Sometimes it can take over `1 min` to build!

Comment: Do you end up with big bundles?

Comment: @MinusFour What do you mean by big bundles? I'm new to gulp and am using my works config. It's seriously slow! Surely gulp can determine which file was saved and babelify it!?

Comment: As in bundles with a bunch of frameworks/libraries. You could just have those as external modules and have browserify bundle code that's only yours.

Comment: Still thinking about this, but as a side note, you don't need to specify `extensions` if you only care about `.js` files. `extensions` is for when you have non `.js` files such as `.jsx`

Comment: @MinusFour - Yeah I've got like 15-20 node_module? Not many libraries as such, maybe only underscore.

Comment: @James111, but you are aware that every time you apply any tiny **change to any js-file**, babel has to **process all js-files**? remove the whole watch for js, and trigger it manually, if whenever you want your js to be recompiled.

Comment: You should definitely use watchify, but your issue may also be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925382/gulp-babel-es2015-transform-very-slow

Comment: @loganfsmyth - I think we'll be switching to web-pack soon.

Comment: Either way :) On small projects you probably won't notice a performance different. Did you look at the npm@2 issue I linked to? Are you on npm@3?

Comment: It might well be that, I've been advised that we're changing to web-pack soon so there's no need to worry about this issue anymore. I haven't heard of other people having the same problem? Maybe gulp just isn't meant for large site development projects. I don't think npm2 is the problem because my colleague is using npm3+ & his packaging time is still 30+

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use **watchify** with **broswerifiy** I think it will speed up the process for incremental builds.

But any way try this

```
gulp.task('babel', function () {
  return browserify({
    entries: 'app/index.js',
    extensions: ['.js'],
    presets: ["es2015", "react"],
    debug: true
    paths: ['app', 'app/layouts','app/components', 'node_modules']
  })
    .transform(babelify.configure({
        ignore: /(node_modules)/
    }))
    .on('error', log_error)
    .bundle()
    .on('error', log_error)
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.app.dist));
});
gulp.task('watch', ['build'],  function() {
  gulp.watch(path.assets.src+'icons/*', ['icons', 'sass']);
  gulp.watch(path.styles.all, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(path.styles.all, ['sass:styleguide']);
  gulp.watch(path.scripts.all, ['babel']);
  gulp.watch(path.templates.all, ['copy:html']);
});
```

If you are using bower add this -

```
.transform(babelify.configure({
            ignore: /(bower_components)|(node_modules)/
        }))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make it any quicker, thanks for taking the time to put it together tho.

Comment: Browserify transforms already only apply to your module code specifically, ignoring deps. Ignoring `node_modules` will be a no-op. No ideal for `bower_components` but the OP never mentioned Bower anyway.

Comment: James is having image of bower bird so I thought :)